# Animation not smooth

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout

I have made a app in which on button click i have slided a linear layout.The code to slide the linear layout is working fine but the problem is that it lags when sliding.Also the height which i have set to slide the layout doesnt look proper on all screen sizes(Specially on Nexus 5).Please do help me out

XMl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_upload_add"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/add" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_upload_options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/choosefile_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <pocketdocs.indiehustlers.com.pocketdocsv2.Utils.TextViewGeneral
                android:id="@+id/tv_upload_gallery"
                style="@style/text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="GALLERY"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"

                android:background="@drawable/line" />

            <pocketdocs.indiehustlers.com.pocketdocsv2.Utils.TextViewGeneral
                android:id="@+id/tv_upload_camera"
                style="@style/text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="CAMERA"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"

                android:background="@drawable/line" />

            <pocketdocs.indiehustlers.com.pocketdocsv2.Utils.TextViewGeneral
                android:id="@+id/tv_upload_file"
                style="@style/text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="FILE"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/all_left_mar"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/all_right_mar"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <pocketdocs.indiehustlers.com.pocketdocsv2.Utils.EditTextFont
            style="@style/edit_text"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_black"
            android:hint="File Title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHint="#000" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            style="@style/edit_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_black"
            android:hint="Type"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHint="#000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textOff="No"
                android:textOn="Yes" />

            <pocketdocs.indiehustlers.com.pocketdocsv2.Utils.TextViewGeneral
                style="@style/text_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="@string/Protect"
                android:textColor="#000" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <pocketdocs.indiehustlers.com.pocketdocsv2.Utils.EditTextFont
            style="@style/edit_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_black"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHint="#000" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/all_left_mar"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/all_right_mar"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <pocketdocs.indiehustlers.com.pocketdocsv2.Utils.ButtonFont
            style="@style/button"
            android:text="UPLOAD" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code

```
if (llUploadOptions.getMeasuredHeight() != 0) {

//                    tvGallery.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                    tvCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                    tvFile.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(llUploadOptions.getMeasuredHeight(),200);
                    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                            int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = llUploadOptions.getLayoutParams();
                            layoutParams.height = val;
                            llUploadOptions.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        }
                    });
                    anim.setDuration(700);
                    anim.start();
                } else {
                    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(llUploadOptions.getMeasuredHeight(),250);
                    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                            int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = llUploadOptions.getLayoutParams();
                            layoutParams.height = val;
                            llUploadOptions.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        }
                    });
                    anim.setDuration(700);
                    anim.start();

                }
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, that you are trying to animate the height of your Layout. That means, that with every animation step you call setLayoutParams() which forces your whole layout (incl. children) to be relayouted by going through the complete view hierarchy and this leads to laggy animation. Layouting things is an expensive operation!

There are some "workarounds" (I'm not sure what you want to do):

1. Since Android 4.0 you simply can use animate layout changes in your xml if you simply want to show / hide a element with animations in your layout
2. For more complex things you may consider to use Transitions framework introduced in Kitkat (Api 19) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3H7nJ4QaD8. Backports: https://github.com/guerwan/TransitionsBackport or https://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere
3. "Fake" the animation by animating views by hand with translation, alpha etc. and set the LayoutParameters only once after the animation has been finished
4. I can't remember how the api is called, but you can subclass from ViewGroup and use it as your root layout. You have to intercept layout changes while animating the height somehow to get a smooth animation (this is how animateLayoutChanges = true works). However thats an advanced topic an I would recommend to go one of the other ways

Comment: Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXpNUeUHfWE  starting at 20:35 ... They are talking about animating height and what I'm talking about in point 4

Comment: Note that Chet is saying:"If a relayout happens while animation you may have a bad day ..." starting at 26:20

Answer (score 3):

you are using `Animators` (not `Animations`), which might be laggy, especially with moving widgets. try [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 200.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f);          
//  these are delta's, check doc for this constructor
//  TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
animation.setDuration(700);     

llUploadOptions.startAnimation(animation);
```

if you want to leave your animated view with final coordinates use

```
animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

but it might not be clickable or other issues might occur. for these you might use

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim)
                {
                };
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim)
                {
                };
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim)
                {
                    //set fixed position in here, using LayoutParams or setTop/setRight etc. methods of View (API 11)
                };
            });
```

edit:

so instead of ValueAnimator you might do smth like this

```
int desiredHeightInPx = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.expandedHeight);
//note those are pixels, not dp. you might set this as =200 or =250 like you have

ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(0, 0, 0, desiredHeightInPx/llUploadOptions.getMeasuredHeight(), Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
animation.setDuration(1000); //ms
llUploadOptions.startAnimation(animation);
```

next steps as above, `fillAfter` or set `AnimationListener` and inside `onAnimationEnd` set final LayoutParams.

be aware that `ScaleAnimation` is scaling, it might be more appropiate to use `RelativeLayout` instead of Linear (which rescales its childers)

Comment: But i want the linearlayout to start below the imageview

Comment: I see you are changing size (height), so more appropriate animation is `ScaleAnimation` (and scale only one dimension). Do with this what you want, I don't understand what means `LinearLayout` "start below" `ImageView`. be aware that animated `View` cannot be larger (e.g. Scale/resize) or outside parent's bounds (Translate/move)

Comment: Please can you provide me with the code ?? as i am very new to android and animations

Comment: what is R.dimen.expandedHeight

Comment: you dimension in resources, should be in dp, no px. your values 200/250 are fixed px, it's not good for different density screens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67208/discussion-between-anuj-and-snachmsm).

Comment: I don't really have time to this, I've provide you some answers and indications, look in docs for Objects form my code snippets, no one will do everything for you